# Spring Data "Data too long for column at row"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have 3 tables in my database.`FOOD_GROUP, FOOD_DESCRIPTION, SECONDARY_FOOD_DESCRIPTION,`. My `Application.java` parses data files in the correct order so that on table can useful to the next. My issue is that when it comes to setting the databankID field in the `SecondaryFoodDescription` class, I get `Data truncation: Data too long for column 'food' at row 1`. This is surprising (at least to me) because, I use the same repository.save method to populate the foodGroup field in the class. `Food`.

EDIT: I'm aware that normally, an error like `Data truncation: Data too long for column 'foodid' at row 1` would mean that what I'm trying to insert is too big for a field. However, I'm trying to insert an Entity. How could my Entity be too big?

Can anyone spot what I'm wrong?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(FoodGroupRepository foodGrouprepository, FoodRepository foodRepository,
                              SecondaryFoodInformationRepository secondaryFoodInformationRepository,
                             ) {
    return (args) -> {

        FoodGroupParser foodGroupParser = new FoodGroupParser();
        FoodGroup foodGroup;
        Map<String, String> foodGroupMap = foodGroupParser.returnFoodGroupData();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : foodGroupMap.entrySet()) {
            foodGroup = new FoodGroup(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            foodGrouprepository.save(foodGroup);
        }

        FoodDescriptionParser foodDescriptionParser = new FoodDescriptionParser();
        List<String[]> listOfFooods = foodDescriptionParser.returnFoodDescriptionData();

        Food foodDescription;
        SecondaryFoodDescription secondaryFoodDescription;
        for (String[] foodItem : listOfFooods) {


            foodDescription = new Food(foodItem[0],foodGrouprepository.findOne(foodItem[1]),foodItem[2],foodItem[4],foodItem[5],foodItem[8]);
            secondaryFoodDescription = new SecondaryFoodDescription();

            foodRepository.save(foodDescription);

            secondaryFoodDescription = new SecondaryFoodDescription(foodRepository.findOne(foodItem[0]),foodItem[6],foodItem[7],foodItem[9],foodItem[10],foodItem[11]);

          secondaryFoodInformationRepository.save(secondaryFoodDescription);



            }
        };
    }
}
```

Repository interfaces:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface FoodGroupRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<FoodGroup,String> {
}


@RepositoryRestResource
public interface FoodRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Food, String>{


List<Food> findByLongDescription(@Param("longDescription") String name);


}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface SecondaryFoodInformationRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SecondaryFoodDescription,Long> {
}
```

Food group entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity
@Table(name = "FOOD_GROUP")
public class FoodGroup implements Serializable{

public FoodGroup(){}

public FoodGroup(String id, String foodName){

    this.setFoodGroupCode(id);
    this.setFoodName(foodName);
}

@Id
@NotNull
@Size(min = 4,max = 4)
private String foodGroupCode;

@NotNull
@Size(max=60)
private String foodName;

public String getFoodGroupCode() {
    return foodGroupCode;
}

public void setFoodGroupCode(String foodGroupCode) {
    this.foodGroupCode = foodGroupCode;
}

public String getFoodName() {
    return foodName;
}

public void setFoodName(String foodName) {
    this.foodName = foodName;
}

}
```

Food entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "FOOD_DESCRIPTION")
public class Food implements Serializable {

@Id
@NotNull()
@Column(name = "NUTRITION_DATA_BANK_ID")
@Size(min = 5, max = 5)
private String nutritionDatabankID;

private FoodGroup foodGroupID;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "foodDescription", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private final Set<NutritionDataForSpecificFood> ndesc = new HashSet<>();

public Set<NutritionDataForSpecificFood> getNutrients() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.ndesc);
}

public void addFood(NutritionDataForSpecificFood specificFood) {
    specificFood.setFoodDescription(this);
    this.ndesc.add(specificFood);
}

@NotNull
@Column(name = "LONG_DESCRIPTION")
@Size(max = 200)
private String longDescription;

@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "COMMON_NAME")
private String commonName;

@Size(max = 65)
@Column(name = "MANUFACTURER_NAME")
private String manufacturerName;


@Size(max = 65)
@Column(name = "SCIENTIFIC_NAME")
private String scientificNameOfFood;


public Food() {
}

public Food(String nutritionDatabankID, FoodGroup foodGroupID, String longDescription, String commonName,
            String manufacturerName, String scientificNameOfFood) {

    this.nutritionDatabankID = nutritionDatabankID;
    this.foodGroupID = foodGroupID;
    this.longDescription = longDescription;
    this.commonName = commonName;
    this.manufacturerName = manufacturerName;
    this.scientificNameOfFood = scientificNameOfFood;

}


public FoodGroup getFoodGroupID() {
    return foodGroupID;
}

public void setFoodGroupID(FoodGroup foodGroupID) {
}

public String getNutritionDatabankID() {
    return nutritionDatabankID;
}

public void setNutritionDatabankID(String nutritionDatabankID) {
    this.nutritionDatabankID = nutritionDatabankID;
}

public String getLongDescription() {
    return longDescription;
}

public void setLongDescription(String longDescription) {
    this.longDescription = longDescription;
}

public String getCommonName() {
    return commonName;
}

public void setCommonName(String commonName) {
    this.commonName = commonName;
}

public String getManufacturerName() {
    return manufacturerName;
}

public void setManufacturerName(String manufacturerName) {
    this.manufacturerName = manufacturerName;
}

public String getScientificNameOfFood() {
    return scientificNameOfFood;
}

public void setScientificNameOfFood(String scientificNameOfFood) {
    this.scientificNameOfFood = scientificNameOfFood;
}

}
```

Secondary Food Info entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity
@Table(name = "SECONDARY_FOOD_DESCRIPTION")
public class SecondaryFoodDescription implements Serializable {

public SecondaryFoodDescription(){}

public SecondaryFoodDescription(Food food,String refuseDescription, String refusePercentage,
                                String caloriesFromProteinFactor, String caloriesFromFatFactor,
                                String caloriesFromCarbsFactor){

    this.food = food;
    this.refuseDescription = refuseDescription;
    this.refuseDescription = refuseDescription;
    this.caloriesFromProteinFactor = caloriesFromProteinFactor;
    this.caloriesFromFatFactor = caloriesFromFatFactor;
    this.caloriesFromCarbsFactor = caloriesFromCarbsFactor;

}


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

private Food food;

@Size(max = 135)
@Column(name = "REFUSE_DESCRIPTION")
private String refuseDescription;

@Column(name = "REFUSE_PERCENTAGE")
private String refusePercentage;

@Column(name = "CALORIES_FROM_PROTEIN_FACTOR")
private String caloriesFromProteinFactor;

@Column(name = "CALORIES_FROM_FAT_FACTOR")
private String caloriesFromFatFactor;

@Column(name = "CALORIES_FROM_CARBS_FACTOR")
private String caloriesFromCarbsFactor;

public String getRefuseDescription() {
    return refuseDescription;
}

public void setRefuseDescription(String refuseDescription) {
    this.refuseDescription = refuseDescription;
}

public String getRefusePercentage() {
    return refusePercentage;
}

public void setRefusePercentage(String refusePercentage) {
    this.refusePercentage = refusePercentage;
}

public String getCaloriesFromProteinFactor() {
    return caloriesFromProteinFactor;
}

public void setCaloriesFromProteinFactor(String caloriesFromProteinFactor) {
    this.caloriesFromProteinFactor = caloriesFromProteinFactor;
}

public String getCaloriesFromFatFactor() {
    return caloriesFromFatFactor;
}

public void setCaloriesFromFatFactor(String caloriesFromFatFactor) {
    this.caloriesFromFatFactor = caloriesFromFatFactor;
}

public String getCaloriesFromCarbsFactor() {
    return caloriesFromCarbsFactor;
}

public void setCaloriesFromCarbsFactor(String caloriesFromCarbsFactor) {
    this.caloriesFromCarbsFactor = caloriesFromCarbsFactor;
}

public Food getFood() {
    return food;
}

public void setFood(Food food) {
    this.food = food;
}

}
```

Comment: it means that the content for column "food" has longer value than the actually mapping. What is the column type defined in your database?

Comment: Yes, I understand what the message means, but in the case - I am referring to an Entity. The ID column for the class `Food` is an alphanumeric with a total length of 5 digits and letters. After saving the Food object to the repository (line 34), I pull it at line 36 to populate the "Food" field in `SecondaryFoodDescription`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to annotate with appropriate relations `@OneToOne`/`@OneToMany`, otherwise the complete object will be serialized and persisted as a BLOB. If the BLOB size is large you get the `Data Truncation` error.

Answer (score 0):

"Solved" by adding a @OneToOne annotation to the field ,`food` in the `SecondaryFoodDescription` entity.

This is an unsatisfying answer though. In the Food entity there is an unannotated field for the entity `FoodGroup`. That field does not produce the "column to long" error.